# Zip file with pass on mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to zip a folder with password on the mac - in the `terminal` :

```
zip -er archive.zip /desktop/foldername
```

It ask me the password , than says :

```
  adding: desktop/name/ (stored 0%)
```

when i open the file, there is no password required, the mac just unzip it when clicked .

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the first / in folder name otherwise give it the full path.

Comment: didn't get you. he is creating the zip so there might be other issue.

Comment: i think hits because it can't find the files, path is wrong so it creates an empty zip instead